# PriviledgedActionException: Able to populate Hbase via Hive, however, unable to query HBase via Hive

Tags: hive, integration, hbase, cloudera, beeswax

I'm using the current Cloudera Quick Start VM. I've created an Hive table with some data. Then, I've created an external table with the Hive Storage Handler. I was able to populate the HBase table. However, while quering the Hive/HBase table, I got the following error (NullpointerException):

```
14/04/16 01:18:51 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hbase (auth:SIMPLE) cause:BeeswaxException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException, log_context:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11, handle:QueryHandle(id:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11, log_context:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11), SQLState:     )
14/04/16 01:18:51 ERROR beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl: Caught BeeswaxException
BeeswaxException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException, log_context:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11, handle:QueryHandle(id:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11, log_context:3ecc8100-e8f8-40a0-916b-00fa5a9b6b11), SQLState:     )
at  com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState.fetch(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:545)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$5.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:986)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$5.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:981)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl.doWithState(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:772)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl.fetch(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:980)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.api.BeeswaxService$Processor$fetch.getResult(BeeswaxService.java:987)
at com.cloudera.beeswax.api.BeeswaxService$Processor$fetch.getResult(BeeswaxService.java:971)
at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I embedded Guava, zookeeper, hbase and hive-hbase-handler JARs. I followed the instructions made in this tutorial: http://www.n10k.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-pt2/

I am using the current Cloudera-Quick-Start VM. Job and Task-Tracker logs as well as Beeswax logs are telling me nothing.

Do you have any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

I am thankfull for any advise!

Best regards, Lena

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:
[Nullpointer exception in HBase MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480858/nullpointer-exception-in-hbase-mapreduce)

The logs were misleading (for me). HBase or Hive was not able to resolve the NameNode.